# model to use for age prediction in r

Tags: r, model

I have ~50,000 customers of which 10,000 are known by age group (under and over 65). I have history of brands purchased by each customer. I want to build a model to predict which age group a customer belongs based on purchase history. I run the model and it is showing some errors (further below).

Questions:

1. Can I use naiveBayes model to predict which age_group a customer belong?
2. How to understand why my model is not working
3. Instead of age_group which model to use for predicting age if I have age of the customer?

Thank very much in advance

```
# building train and test sets
set.seed(100) 
train_set_indexes <- sample (1:nrow(demand_by_customer_brand_year_2018_row), size = 5000) 

train_set <- demand_by_customer_brand_year_2018_row [train_set_indexes, ]
test_set <- demand_by_customer_brand_year_2018_row [-train_set_indexes, ]

# Applying a model (naiveBayes) on train set

library(e1071)
model_age <- naiveBayes(Customer_Age_Group ~ ., data = train_set)

# Predicting the class labels of the train set
predicted_labels <- predict(model_age, test_set)
summary(model_age)

True_labels <- test_set[,1]
head(True_labels)

table1 <- table (True_labels,predicted_labels)
table1


# output of summary(model_age)

        Length Class  Mode   
apriori   2    table  numeric
tables  741    -none- list   
levels    0    -none- NULL   
call      4    -none- call  

# Output when processing table1 <- table (True_labels,predicted_labels)

Error in table(True_labels, predicted_labels) : object 'True_labels' not found
```

Comment: Brian, the votes are mounting to migrate this to [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). I believe there is no action required on your part. This is not a vote against the question, more a migration to where academic discussions like this are more appropriate. (SO is more about programming problems, which this does not appear to be.) Good luck!

Comment: There should also be an error after your run `True_labels <- test_set[,1]`, could you check that?

Comment: True_labels <- test_set[,1]
>

Comment: no error it is running fine

Comment: here is true labels showing up:  [1] "Mom"    "Mom"    "Mom"    "Mom"    "Senior" "Senior" "Senior" "Senior" "Senior" "Senior" "Mom"    "Senior" "Senior" "Senior" "Senior" "Senior" "Senior" "Senior" "Senior" "Senior" "Senior"
  [22] "Senior" "Mom"    "Senior"

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem:

Before I had chr format:
'data.frame':   1000 obs. of  742 variables:
 $ Customer_Age_Group                  : chr  "Mom" "Mom" "Mom" "Senior" ...

When I converted it into factor w/2 levels it worked
'data.frame':   1000 obs. of  742 variables:
 $ Customer_Age_Group                  : Factor w/ 2 levels "Mom","Senior": 1 1 1 2 1 1